# What is best practice of writing select query where no. of dynamic joins and conditions are required

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using dynamic query concept to dynamically construct my query based on input parameters to my stored procedure. 
Based on input I have to decide

1. ***Dynamically I need to decide columns value need to fetch from which table ?***
2. ***What JOINS need to apply ?***
3. ***What will be my where condition (based on filter criteria)?***

**I am sharing a sample code snippet, for the approach I am using. As below**

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `EMS_teamBasedUserInfo_for_selectedArtifact`$$

CREATE  PROCEDURE `EMS_teamBasedUserInfo_for_selectedArtifact`(
IN IN_org_type_id BIGINT,
IN IN_org_id BIGINT,
IN IN_artifact_type_id VARCHAR(100), 
IN IN_artifact_id VARCHAR(100), 
IN IN_artifact_id_list VARCHAR(200), 
IN IN_outer_delimiter VARCHAR(2), 
IN IN_inner_delimiter VARCHAR(2), 
IN IN_team_Id BIGINT)

BEGIN  
        DECLARE VAR_artifact_type VARCHAR(20);
        DECLARE VAR_artifact_ids VARCHAR(20);
        DECLARE VAR_common_column VARCHAR(20000);
        DECLARE VAR_selective_column VARCHAR(20000);
        DECLARE VAR_common_join VARCHAR(20000);
        DECLARE VAR_selective_join VARCHAR(20000);
        DECLARE VAR_common_condition VARCHAR(20000);
        DECLARE VAR_selective_condition VARCHAR(20000);

        SET VAR_common_column = CONCAT('SELECT ', 
                                            'Users_Orgs.userId,',
                                            'User_.screenName,',
                                            'User_.firstName,',
                                            'User_.middleName,',
                                            'User_.lastName,',
                                            'User_.emailAddress');
        SET VAR_common_join = CONCAT('FROM ',
                                        'Users_Orgs ',
                                    'INNER JOIN User_ ',
                                        'ON(Users_Orgs.userId = User_.userId)');
        SET VAR_common_condition = CONCAT('WHERE ', 
                                            'organizationId = ', IN_org_id);

        IF IN_team_Id > 0 THEN
            SET VAR_selective_join = CONCAT(VAR_selective_join,
                                            ' INNER JOIN Users_Teams ',
                                                'ON(Users_Orgs.userId = Users_Teams.userId)');
            SET VAR_selective_condition = CONCAT(VAR_selective_join,
                                            ' AND Users_Teams.teamId = ', IN_team_Id);
        END IF;

        SELECT typeName INTO VAR_org_type_name FROM V1_OrganizationType WHERE organizationTypeId = IN_org_type_id;
        SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(NAME)>0 THEN NAME ELSE '-1' END INTO VAR_artifact_type FROM ApplicationParamValue WHERE appParamValueId = CAST(IN_artifact_type_id AS UNSIGNED);


        IF UPPER(VAR_org_type_name) = UPPER('IMS') THEN

            IF UPPER(VAR_artifact_type) = UPPER('Project') THEN

                IF IN_team_Id > 0 THEN
                    SET VAR_selective_join = CONCAT(VAR_selective_join,
                                                    ' INNER JOIN EMS_artifact_team_mapping ',
                                                        'ON(Users_Teams.teamId = EMS_artifact_team_mapping.teamId)');
                    SET VAR_selective_condition = CONCAT(VAR_selective_join,
                                                    ' AND EMS_artifact_team_mapping.teamId = ', IN_team_Id,
                                                    ' AND EMS_artifact_team_mapping.artifactTypeId = ', (CAST(IN_artifact_type_id AS UNSIGNED)));

                    IF (CAST(IN_artifact_id AS UNSIGNED)) > 0 THEN
                        SET VAR_selective_condition = CONCAT(VAR_selective_join,
                                                        ' AND EMS_artifact_team_mapping.artifactId = ', (CAST(IN_artifact_id AS UNSIGNED)));
                    END IF;
                END IF;
            ELSEIF UPPER(VAR_artifact_type) = UPPER('-1') THEN
                -- SET VAR_artifact_ids = CONCAT(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(project_id) FROM EMS_project WHERE organizationId = IN_org_id);
            END IF;
        ELSEIF UPPER(VAR_org_type_name) = UPPER('GMS') THEN

            IF UPPER(VAR_artifact_type) = UPPER('Project') THEN

                IF IN_team_Id > 0 THEN
                    SET VAR_selective_join = CONCAT(VAR_selective_join,
                                                    ' INNER JOIN EMS_artifact_team_mapping ',
                                                        'ON(Users_Teams.teamId = EMS_artifact_team_mapping.teamId)');
                    SET VAR_selective_condition = CONCAT(VAR_selective_join,
                                                    ' AND EMS_artifact_team_mapping.teamId = ', IN_team_Id,
                                                    ' AND EMS_artifact_team_mapping.artifactTypeId = ', (CAST(IN_artifact_type_id AS UNSIGNED)));

                    IF (CAST(IN_artifact_id AS UNSIGNED)) > 0 THEN
                        SET VAR_selective_condition = CONCAT(VAR_selective_join,
                                                        ' AND EMS_artifact_team_mapping.artifactId = ', (CAST(IN_artifact_id AS UNSIGNED)));
                    END IF;
                END IF;
            ELSEIF UPPER(VAR_artifact_type) = UPPER('-1') THEN
                -- SET VAR_artifact_ids = CONCAT(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(project_id) FROM EMS_project WHERE organizationId = IN_org_id);
            END IF;
        END IF;


        SET @SQL := CONCAT(VAR_common_column, ' ', VAR_selective_column, ' ', VAR_common_join, ' ', VAR_selective_join, ' ', VAR_common_condition, ' ', VAR_selective_condition);

        -- select @SQL;
        PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL; 

        EXECUTE stmt;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**I want to know what is best approach to do it ? Is there any other better approaches are there?**

Comment: Don't tag products not involved...

Comment: For which tag you are basically talking about ?

Comment: I can't see the above code working with both MySQL and Oracle. Which one are you using?

Comment: I think this is the common requirement across the Databases (whatever we are using). Currently X DB then some other day Y DB.

Comment: I am using MySQL. And I just kept a sample code of snnipet to share that complexity which I need to take care and the app which I am using